# If int *p is a pointer to int, why &p has type **p?

Tags: c, pointers

I've read a lot of tutorials about pointers and I did answered a lot of exercises about them, including reading obscure declaration, the spiral rule, etc.

However, there's one simple thing that I still don't get and I haven't seen mentioned in any place.

Consider int *p.
p is a pointer to int.
I know that I can get the address of the variable that holds this pointer with &p. Right. But &p has type int**... why? What does it exactly mean? (of course, it is a pointer to pointer to int, but I don't understand the sense of this)

This question was motivated by the following code:

```
int main() {
   node * curr, * root;
   int i;

   root = NULL;

   for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
      curr = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      curr->left = curr->right = NULL;
      curr->val = rand();
      insert(&root, curr);
   }
```

and the call

```
insert(&(*tree)->right, item);
```

EDIT:
OK, I got that & adds another level of indirection (I wonder why I haven't seen this mentioned in all texts I've read about pointers, they usually just tell about the address)
.
I just don't understand where this pointer comes from. I wonder why it exists if I didn't create it, for example. I really apologize if my question is not clear. I didn't expected such negative reaction...

Comment: If "int i is an int, why &i has type int*?" (Every address-of adds another [pointer] indirection.)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, in the sense that you've answered your own question.  A pointer to pointer to int holds the address of the pointer.

Comment: Having a pointer-to-pointer-to-int lets you change which int the original pointer points to.

Comment: `&p` has type `int **`  (not `**int` or `**p`)

Comment: Posting the code context and definition of `tree` and `item` would help.

Comment: @user2864740, thank you. But I just don't understand where this points comes from. I wonder why it exists if I didn't create it, for example. I really apologize if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a declared variable `var` of type `foo`, its address `&var` has type "pointer to `foo`", or `foo*`:

```
foo var; // var has type foo, &var has type foo*
```

In your case, the variable's type happens to be a pointer type. That makes no difference.

```
int n;  // n has type int,  &n has type int*
int *p; // p has type int*, &p has type int**
```

For some types, particularly array types, you might have to add parentheses to express the type of the address:

```
int a[10]; // a has type int[10], &a has type int(*)[10]
```

It's still the same idea; you just need extra parentheses to avoid syntactic ambiguity. If that's too confusing, you can hide the array type behind a typedef (which is usually *not* a good idea):

```
typedef int arr10[10]; // arr10 is an alias for the type int[10]
arr10 a;               // a has type arr10, &a has type arr10*
```

The program `cdecl` can be very useful for decoding C's admittedly confusing type syntax. There's an online version at http://cdecl.org/

---

> I just don't understand where this pointer comes from. I wonder why it exists if I didn't create it, for example.

It's important to distinguish between pointer *values* and pointer *objects* (variables).

The expression `&n` yields a pointer value (a value of type `int*`), but does not create an object of that type. Similarly, the expression `42` yields a value of type `int`, but that value isn't stored in an `int` object unless you create one.

The common use of the unqualified word "pointer" can be confusing, especially when the distinction between values and objects is important, as it is here.

Some people have argued that the word "pointer" should refer only to a pointer *object*, but in fact the C standard uses the word to refer to pointer values. For example, the description of `malloc()` says that

> The **`malloc`** function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first lines presented new information for me; I wonder why none of the texts I've read about points so far mention it. But, copying the comment I gave in the original question: I just don't understand where this points comes from. I wonder why it exists if I didn't create it, for example. I really apologize if my question is not clear.

Comment: @user35477: I think you mean "pointers", not "points". It's important to distinguish between pointer *values* and pointer *objects*. The expression `&n` yields a pointer value (a value of type `int*`, but does not create an object of that type. Similarly, the expression `42` yields a value of type `int`, but that value isn't stored in an `int` object unless you create one.

Comment: Yep, that was a typo. Now I understand. That responds my question. Thank you very much. (may you edit your answer with this new information, so I can accept it please?)

Answer (score 0):

It's the address of the pointer. And the address points to the pointer to the int.